# Groupbox alignment of title in qt doesn`t work. Why?

Tags: c++, qt

I created a simple MainWindow form in Qt 4.8.4 designer, in preview title is placed in top left corner as it should be, but when i use this form in a simple program which writen in Eclipse with QT plugin, the title placed straight at top top center which is not right. When i use ui.groupBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight); or left before show(), nothing happen the title stays at the center. What may cause this? Program is minimalistic and there only group box and nothing else.

Comment: Also when i use simple preview in QT Designer(without styles Windows, Motif etc.) the title stays at the center.

Comment: seen in Qt5 (5.5.1) too...

Comment: see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49068

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a style sheet to it like this:

```
ui->groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox::title {subcontrol-position: right;}");
```